# Is it useful to install a dual boot clean windows 10 for diagnostic purpose?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

My Windows 10 laptop is having a boot problem. I sent it to the service center and they told me it was possibly the software's problem and asked me to do a clean Windows 10 reinstall.

I don't want to reinstall because most people on the internet says it is the hard disk that goes wrong, so I come up with a nice idea. What if I install a new Windows 10 as a dual boot system and use it to see if it really is the software's problem? Does it help? Can it fully replace reinstalling Windows directly?

Comment: What is the boot problem? What steps you took to fix the boot problem? check the health of the hard disk.

Comment: @Zeeshan It is the same problem of [this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-920-Boot-Fail/td-p/3978664). It fails randomly. Booting about 20 times will succeed 1 time. Booting while shaking the laptop is effective, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this (installing it along side your other copy) will not give you the *objective* view you seek. In fact, it may not work at all. Problem is

- The new Windows install will *see* the other installed copy, and make changes to the (newly) installed copy, based on knowing the other copy exists. If it allows an additional install at all.
- If it's the *drive* itself. How could you possibly ascertain that if you're installing to the *same* drive?

While what you're attempting to do is a good plan. The only good way to determine that it is *not* the drive, or that it *is* the previous install. Would be (if possible) to find another drive, and (temporarily) *replace* your current drive with the new one, and perform a *fresh* install to that drive.